# Vagrant, puppet and virtual box

Tags: vagrant, puppet

Getting this error when I run the command - `vagrant up`

> Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list emacs' returned 1:
>   Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for
>   repository: nodesource. Please verify its path and try again

Comment: This lacks all sorts of information. What base image? What Puppet modules? Is the instance's network operational? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Although some details around OS etc. would have helped but the error seems to be coming when trying to do an "yum update". Similar error has been answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109585/yum-update-fails-error-cannot-retrieve-repository-metadata-repomd-xml-for-re). So technically it is not even a Puppet error. If you need a basic sandbox for trying puppet using Vagrant then you can use the repo [here](http://github.com/vishal-biyani/puppet-lab)